# How to center social buttons in bootstrap login page?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using django-allauth, bootstrap, font awesome and [bootstrap-social](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/) for the social media login buttons in my login form. I can't figure out how to center the social buttons within my login-well below.  It appears to be aligning to the right of the login well instead of centered.  What should I be doing?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bayman/n2ev1eo6/1/)

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
      <div class="well login-well">
        <div class="socialaccount_ballot col-md-11">
          <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
            <li>
              <a title="Google" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-md socialaccount_provider btn-google" href="/accounts/google/login/?process=+login+">
                <i class="fa fa-google"></i>Log in with Google
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a title="Facebook" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-md socialaccount_provider btn-facebook" href="/accounts/facebook/login/?process=+login+">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Log in with Facebook
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a title="Twitter" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-md socialaccount_provider btn-twitter" href="/accounts/twitter/login/?process=+login+">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Log in with Twitter
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <hr>
          <form class="login" method="POST" action="/login/">
            <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_login">Username</label><input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="id_login" maxlength="30" name="login" placeholder="Username" required="required" title="" type="text" /></div>
            <div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="id_password">Password</label><input class="form-control" id="id_password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" title="" type="password" /></div>
<div class="form-group"><div class="checkbox"><label for="id_remember"><input class="" id="id_remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" /> Remember Me</label></div></div>
            <div class="form-group pull-center">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <small><a class="text-muted" href="/password_reset/">Forgot Password?</a></small>
          <br>
          <small><a class="text-muted" href="/signup/">Sign up</a></small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
.socialaccount_providers li a.socialaccount_provider {
  rem-border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 2px;
  rem-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  -padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  rem-font-size: 1.2em;

}

.socialaccount_providers li a.socialaccount_provider:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.socialaccount_providers li a.socialaccount_provider.facebook {
  background: #4B67A3; 
  color: #fff;
}
.socialaccount_providers li a.socialaccount_provider.facebook:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  content: "\f082";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

What I want it to look like when social buttons are centered:
[image: login buttons]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul.socialaccount_providers` has a inexplicit `padding-left = 40px;`

Just throwing in `.socialaccount_providers {padding-left:0;}` fixes it.